# How would I display circles next to each line in a text field like the Notes app?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to create something like the Apple Notes app. The one problem specifically I need help with:

```
1. Make a checklist, and each line will have a circle next to it.
2. Hit return to go to a new line with a new circle on that line. <- this is what I need help with
```

How would I begin creating something like this? I can do something like:

```swift
HStack {
    Image(systemName: "circle")
    TextField(...)
}
```

but I'm not sure how to create a new row of this if `return` is pressed.

Comment: I recommend you edit your question and focus on one thing. It looks like you want to build an entire app here haha

Comment: @Luffy that's fair! I've edited the question to focus on one issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct CustomToggleStyle: ToggleStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        HStack{
            Button{
                configuration.isOn.toggle()
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: configuration.isOn ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "circle")
                    .foregroundColor(configuration.isOn ? .yellow : .gray)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var task: String = ""
    @State private var flag = false
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 5) {
            Toggle("", isOn: $flag)
                .toggleStyle(CustomToggleStyle())
            TextField("Add your task here", text: $task)
        }
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: That is helpful but runs into the issue of 1. hitting return doesn't add a new row and 2. I can't select all the text across all rows.

Comment: @VladtheImpala Yeah, I'm trying to figure out that part right now.